# Removing duplicate labels in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I want to label the names of locations from a shapefile field in ArcMap.  I tried to do it by going to Layer Properties>Labels.  However, as I have multiple observations per given location, I am getting multiple labels for that location.  I have numerous locations over a large area and I don't want labels to clutter the map.  Is it possible to display a single label representing each unique location in this situation?

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please edit the title of your question to include enough information for future visitors to be able to find this question when looking for the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you want to goto labels > placement properties > duplicate labels, and make sure you have checked the radio box for remove duplicate labels,  alternatively you could check place one label for feature.

[image]

Also there are other map engines like maplex label engine that can do some further refining of your labels.

Comment: Thanks @user3338197.  I noticed that option too but it wasn't possible to make a selection as it was grayed-out.

Comment: so you are dealing with point data that has duplicate labels?

Comment: Exactly.  I have tens of points at a given location and numerous such locations over a large area.

Comment: ok so there are a couple options to do this, one is described here http://support.esri.com/es/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/27419  , a second method is to create a duplicate layer of your points,  for the first layer have the points visible with no labels,  for the second layer use a definition query to keep only 1 point per set (ie keep only one central point to the features you want to label) make this point invisible (no color no fill) but turn the labels on for this invisible point.  This is allow arc to label to show a single label for the entire cluster of points.

Comment: I tried the second option and it worked!  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah that second method is a tried and true work around for that little issue. I use it all the time =)   You may want to accept the answer if you can so others will know it worked for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dissolve to that shape just for displaying labels, meanwhile maintaining visible the original shape and hiding the symbol for dissolved shape.