# Show only one label for multiple points with same value in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling

I have polygon shapefile which has same id . doesn't look nice with the normal label display
I want show one block (multiple polygon ) by same name

Comment: Are you using the Standard or Maplex Labeling Engine?  What options have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a basic answer:

[Remove duplicate labels between two identical points](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252894/remove-duplicate-labels-between-two-identical-points)

As mentioned in the link, you can set the distance high to remove all duplicates. But if you want this removal to be scale dependent, you can use page units (inches or points) rather than absolute ground/map units such as kilometers.
Also keep in mind that this duplicate removal refers to records within a layer and will not remove duplicate labels from any other layer.